# Why is my bird or paradise producing crinkled leaves?

Tags: identification, leaves

Can someone help me please?

I bought this bird of paradise last year! I repotted it in March and it’s grown soooooo much! When I repotted it the roots were thick and curled around each other so I knew it needed repotting! There weren’t any signs of root rot

I have 4 stems / plants in 1 pot (this is how it came) and 1 of the stems is producing new leaves that come out crinkled / shrivelled! The roots are starting to come out of the drainage holes again! I repotted it into a pot that is 5cm bigger than the one it came in and it was taller too!

I’m wondering if it’s too over crowded or I’ve accidentally damaged the roots? Should I repot it again even though I only did it a few months ago? I’m unsure what to do!

Any help would be massively appreciated

[image: before repotting]

[image: now / after repotting]

[image: stems]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's low humidity speaking out in real life. Better outside than in. Spray water a few times a day until leaves smooth out and unfurl. Otherwise, your plant's in good health. But how natural is a pot for a tropical plant?